# Wordpress changing element.style with CSS

Tags: css, wordpress

I want to change the color of the social icons (on the left side of the screenshot). Since I have no clue how to change it in WordPress, I tried it with CSS. But now I noticed that I have to change the element. style and I don't know how... I tried just changing the color in the element. style and copying into the additional CSS in WordPress, but it doesn't work. On the screenshot, you can see what I mean. Is there a solution to this problem?

[image: Screenshot]

This is what I tried:

```
element.style {
    --wpz-social-icons-block-item-color: #FF0000;
    --wpz-social-icons-block-item-color-hover: #FF0000;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try with this following code in wordpress customizer > Additional CSS

```
.social-icon-link{
 --wpz-social-icons-block-item-color: black !important;
--wpz-social-icons-block-item-color-hover:
red !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but this changes all the social icons, but I just want to change the right social icon. Any idea how I can achieve this?

Comment: I think you should use child selector like nth-child(1), nth-child(2) etc...

Answer (score 1):

I think that what makes color is the element inside a `<span class="social-icon socicon socicon-icon-instagram">`

But anyway you are trying to change something via style, and if you want to do like this you´ll hace to use something like

```
style="background-color:#000"
```

or wathever, color, font-size etc

But in this case I will use a new style, like

```
.socicon-icon-instagram {color:#000;}
```

And maybe depends of the template you´ll need to add !important to CSS class to get the color...like this

```
 .socicon-icon-instagram {color:#000!important;}
```

It is not a good practice but sometimes is necesary